# Изменить отправителя в функции

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Здравствуйте, почему-то не выходит изменить отправителя в обработчике форм на php. Вот код обработчика:

```php
$recepient = "1111111";
$sitename = "Название сайта";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $phone \nТекст: $text";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail(
  $recepient,
  $pagetitle,
  $message,
  "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient"
);
```

Изменяю значение в From, но это почему-то не работает. Обьясните в чем дело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай `From:` первым текстом в письме. Но сама проблема скорее всего в пробеле перед ним.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать такую схему для формирования писем:

```
$to = "user@example.com";
$from = "admin@example.com";
$subject = "Subj";
$message = "Message";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n".
           "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\""."\r\n".
           "From: $from"."\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

А дополнительные поля добавлять уже в переменную $headers по шаблону, чтобы не запутаться.

Comment: у Вас в ответе явная путаница с кавычками. Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @МихаилРебров поправил, спасибо.